# Two particles are suspended in the air -- what is the tension and acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

In the following problem:

[image]

(i) I have found the tension in $S_1$ to be $ 2 N $. However, I am a little confused about the force diagram I'm making for particle B. I am guessing that the weight on B is going to be $m_Ag + m_Bg$. Is that correct?
Also, what is the tension in $S_2$ going to be? I am trying to imagine this, and it seems as if $S_2$ will have to have a tension force large enough to support Particle A and $S_1$. So will the tension in $S_2$ be the tension in $S_1$ + whatever the weight is at particle B?

(ii) First off -- why would the air resistance be different for both particles, when they are the same mass?
I have tried formulating an equation for part ii:
$$ 0.2g + 0.2g - 0.4 - 0.2 ...(tension forces)... = ma$$
(a) I suppose m here (for ma) would be 0.4, the sum of both masses?
(b) How do the individual tensions go into the formula here? I'm unsure about how to calculate tension as well.

Thank you!